# Making part of a split string public, and the other part local

Tags: c#, string, split

Apologies about the (possibly) basic question, but I am attempting to split a string, and making one part of the string public, so I can call it later in the form in a different class.

It is a simple Skype chat bot, and it reads the message sent to me for processing. However, I am attempting to make it so that if someone sent a command with two words - e.g. !command name - the !command command will be processed, and later in the form, I will use the second part of the split string to be able to process it. Here is what I am attempting -

The splitting and reading of the message -

```
  public void skype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
    {
        if (msg.Body.IndexOf(trigger) == 0 && TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived == status)
        {
            string command = msg.Body.Remove(0, trigger.Length).ToLower();
            var splitted = command.Split(' ');
            string command1 = splitted[0];
            string name = splitted[1];
            msg.Chat.SendMessage(nick + ProcessCommand(command1));
        }
    }
```

There are several other commands in this chat bot, so there is a switch containing different outcomes - as for !command, I have -

```
 case "command":
 result = command();
 break;
```

And finally -

```
       private string command()
    {
        WebRequest.Create("API I have" + name);
        new WebClient().DownloadString("API I have" + name);
    }
```

I would like to be able to use 'name' here, from the split message. Thanks, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make it a `public` property in the containing class. Or a `private` one if you just use it internally in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, define the pattern you want to use to parse your inbound messages. It seems like you have multiple commands that probably have different parameters, but all commands take the following form:

```
![Command String] [Command Parameters]
```

So you will want a class that represents that:

```
public class ChatCommand
{
    private string _command;
    public string Command { get { return _command; } }

    private string _parameters;
    public string Parameters { get { return _parameters; } }

    public ChatCommand(string command, string parameters) {
        _command = command;
        _parameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

From there, you will need to adjust the method you posted to look like this. Notice that we are now telling split to stop splitting when it has 2 strings to return (basically splitting on the first space only).

```
public void skype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
{
    if (msg.Body.IndexOf(trigger) == 0 && TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived == status)
    {
        string command = msg.Body.Remove(0, trigger.Length).ToLower();
        var splitted = command.Split(new [] { ' ' }, 2);
        var command1 = new ChatCommand(splitted[0], splitted[1])
        msg.Chat.SendMessage(nick + ProcessCommand(command1));
    }
}
```

The reason we are leaving the parameters in one string instead of splitting them out is because this gives you the flexibility to format parameters for different commands differently. For example, maybe you want to have a command to send a picture and the second parameters is a URL, or it could be JSON data or binary file data.

Now your ProcessCommand function can look like this:

```
public void ProcessCommand(ChatCommand command) {
    switch(command.Command) {
        case "command":
            //I am code specific to that command and I should know what is contained in the Parameters property of the command
            Console.WriteLine("Name is " + command.Parameters);
        break;
    }
}
```

Then you're done! You can add more commands with any parameters you would like.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, I would like to say that this solves my problem very well. Thank you so very much! Although I have one issue -
msg.Chat.SendMessage(nick + ProcessCommand(command1));
is giving me an error of -
Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'void'
Apologies for bothering you, but what can I do about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. If you are expecting a string to come back from ProcessCommand, you need to change it from a void function to a string function, and make sure you return the appropriate string from each of your cases.

Comment: Ah, no worries! I'll make sure I fix that :) Thank you once again!